# Tab bar disappeared when back to initial view controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller, rootviewcontroller

i have 2 view controllers then tab bar controller connected to 3 navigation controller , each navigation connected to multiple views .
The point that from one of these views that is connected to one of navigation controllers , i want to back again to the start screen , it good by this 2 lines :

```
let loginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = loginViewController
```

but after i do this and want to navigate again to the tab bar its disappeared from the view . I used this to navigate to tab bar :

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let viewTabController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"MainTabBarController") as! MainTabBarController
        viewTabController.selectedIndex = 1

        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = viewTabController
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `instantiateViewController` you are making new instances of view controllers in memory while there is no need in your case , you have created them before. so you can dissmis your `tabBar` and go back to first screen like this (initial `viewcontroller` must be embeded into a navigation controller) :

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let navigationController = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
navigationController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

for bringing back `tabBar` you can either save its instance in your app delegate and present it or use a storyboard segue to present it modally 
:)